# R function to compute variance of average of correlated random variables

Tags: r, correlation, variance, covariance, sum

I want to calculate the variance of the average of *n* correlated variables. I found a formula for that in Borenstein et al. (2009) *Introduction to Meta-Analysis*.

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mY_i\right)=\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^2\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i\right) = \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^2\left(\sum_{i=1}^m V_i + \sum_{i\ne j}r_{ij}\sqrt{V_i}\sqrt{V_j}\right).$$

I think that this the same formula as here [Variance of average of $n$ correlated random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391740/variance-of-average-of-n-correlated-random-variables), except it is based on correlations instead of variances.

I've implemented the formula in `R` like this

```
# Estimates
est <- c(v1 = 1, v2 = 1.3, v3 = 1.1, v4 = 1.2)
# Variance of estimates
var_est <- c(v1 = 0.05, v2 = 0.10, v3 = 0.15, v4 = 0.20)
# Correlations among estimates
cor_v <- c(   1, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3,
           -0.5,    1,  0.3,  0.2,
           -0.4,  0.3,    1,  0.1,
           -0.3,  0.2,  0.1,    1)
correlations <- matrix(cor_v, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, 
                       dimnames = list(names(var_est), names(var_est)))
row.names(correlations) <- names(var_est)
colnames(correlations) <- names(var_est)
covar_tot <- 0
for(v1 in names(var_est)){
  for(v2 in names(var_est)){
    if(v1 != v2){
      i_j <- correlations[v1, v2] * sqrt(var_est[v1]) * sqrt(var_est[v2])
      covar_tot <- covar_tot + i_j
    }
  }
}

# Average of estimates
mean(est)
# [1] 1.15

# Variance of average of estimates
unname((1/length(var_est)) ^ 2 * (sum(var_est) + covar_tot))
# [1] 0.02904385
```

My questions are:
Does the implementation look correct?
Better yet, is there is an `R` library that accepts variances and correlations of estimates and returns the variance of average (or sum) of estimates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When implementing statistical formulas, *simplicity is your friend.*  Consequently, **this formula is best expressed in matrix form when you are considering programming it.**

To achieve such an expression, let $V = (v_{ij})$ be the covariance matrix for a (column) vector of random variables $\mathbf Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)^\prime.$  The variances $v_{ii} = \sigma_i^2$ are the diagonal entries, equal to the squares of the standard deviations.  (Your formula assumes these are all nonzero.)

The correlation matrix $R=(r_{ij})$ is obtained by dividing all rows and all columns by their respective values of $\sigma_i:$

$$ r_{ij} = \frac{v_{ij}}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}.$$

Consequently, $V$ can be recovered from $R$ and the standard deviations by solving this equation, giving

$$ v_{ij} = r_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j.$$

In matrix form this can be written

$$V = \Sigma R \Sigma$$

where $\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_m.$

Your formula is a special example of the covariance of two linear combinations, say

$$X = a_1 Y_1 + \cdots + a_m Y_m = \mathbf a^\prime \mathbf Y;\quad Z = b_1 Y_1 + \cdots + b_m Y_m = \mathbf b^\prime \mathbf Y$$

for two fixed (non-random column) vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b.$  In the question, both these vectors are

$$\mathbf a = \mathbf b = \left(\frac{1}{m}, \ldots, \frac{1}{m}\right)^\prime = \frac{1}{m}\left(1,1,\ldots,1\right)^\prime$$

and you wish to compute the associated covariance

$$\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf a^\prime \mathbf Y) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,Z).$$

Since for any vectors $\mathbf a$  and $\mathbf b,$

$$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf a^\prime \mathbf Y, \mathbf b^\prime \mathbf Y) = \mathbf{a}^\prime V \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a}^\prime \Sigma R \Sigma \mathbf{b},$$

*this is what you should program.*  Why?

1. It is **simple**.
2. Therefore it is more likely to be **correctly implemented**.
3. Therefore it is much **clearer** to any reader what it is intended to do (and what it actually does).
4. Therefore it is **easier to maintain**.
5. It is far **more efficient** (`R` can capitalize on multiple cores, vectorized arithmetic, *etc.*)
6. It is **more general**: it can be applied in many similar situations where $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ do not have the special values in the question.

---

Here is a direct, unoptimized implementation in `R` to show how this analysis leads to effective code.

```R
variance <- function(a, b = a, sigma2 = rep(1, length(a)), R = diag(1, length(a))) {
  sigma <- sqrt(sigma2)
  (a * sigma) %*% R %*% (b * sigma)
}
```

This begs the ultimate question: *How can we tell that a software implementation is correct?*  One way is to compare it to a known correct solution.  A wise choice of test cases can help, but it *always* is useful to test random inputs: they can present unanticipated problems.

Here is such a test of this implementation.

```R
m <- 4 # Must be 2 or greater for this to make sense
check <- replicate(50, {
  Y <- matrix(rnorm(m^2), m)
  a <- rnorm(m)
  b <- rnorm(m)

  c(Direct = cov(Y %*% a, Y %*% b),
    `Our solution` = variance(a, b, diag(var(Y)), cor(Y)))
})

if(1 == (1 - sum((check["Direct", ] - check["Our solution", ])^2))) {
  message("Everything checks.")
} else {
  stop("There's an error!")
}
```

It creates $50$ datasets of vectors $Y$ and $50$ pairs of vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b.$  In each case it computes the covariance of the two linear combinations using the built-in `cov` function and also uses this solution based on the correlation matrix (computed using the built-in `cor` function) and the individual variances (using the built-in `var` function).  At the end it compares the two sets of results.  When the sum of squares of differences is negligible compared to $1,$ it concludes that "everything checks."  Otherwise it warns you there's a problem.

The output when I run it always is "Everything checks."

Now that we have some comfort this method is correct, let's apply it to the data in the question.

```R
sigma2 <- c(v1 = 0.05, v2 = 0.10, v3 = 0.15, v4 = 0.20)
R <- matrix(c(   1, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3,
              -0.5,    1,  0.3,  0.2,
              -0.4,  0.3,    1,  0.1,
              -0.3,  0.2,  0.1,    1), 4)

# The calculations...
m <- length(sigma2)
c(variance(rep(1/m, m), sigma2 = sigma2, R = R))
```

> [1] 0.02904385

*The output differs from that shown in the question.*  If you feel it still would be worthwhile to debug that code, be aware there are several problems with it, including the use of an undefined variable `var_tot` and an error in the variance formula itself.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really pedagogical explanation! And thank you for adding the formatted formula. Yes, I changed a variable name but forgot to update it everywhere, I've edited now. It would be really helpful if you can point out the error in the variance formula - is it in my script or is Borenstein's formula wrong?

Comment: The formula is correct.  The problem is that you clobbered your data with the line `correlations <- diag(4)`.  Remove that and the answer will be correct.

Comment: Doh! That line was a remnant of testing a zero-correlation structure. I removed it and it works. Thank you for a thorough explanation, the improved function, and pointing out my somewhat embarrassing errors. Much appreciated!