# Variance of average of  correlated random variable where  is random variable also

Tags: correlation, variance, mean, random-variable, intraclass-correlation

I have a sum of *n* correlated variables $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and would like to estimate the variance of the sum. I do it with two different methods.

**Firstly**, I can decompose sum as multiplication of the average of $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and *n*. Next, I use a formula for variance of product of variables: $Var(Z \centerdot Y) = Var(Z) \centerdot Var(Y) + E^2[Y] \centerdot Var(Z) + E^2[Z] \centerdot Var(Y)$, call it **formula #1**.
So I get:

$$
Var(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = E^2[n] \centerdot Var(\bar{X}) + E^2[\bar{X}] \centerdot Var(n) + Var(\bar{X}) \centerdot Var(n) = Var(\bar{X})  \centerdot (E^2[n] +  Var(n)) + E^2[\bar{X}] \centerdot Var(n) = Var(\bar{X}) \centerdot E[n^2] + E^2[\bar{X}] \centerdot Var(n) 
$$

**Secondly**, I use a formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables), which is said to be working for sum of correlated variables with random sample size: $Var(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = E[n] \centerdot Var(X) + E^2[X] \centerdot Var(n)$, call it **formula #2**.

Because **formula #1** and **formula #2** for the same thing:
$$
Var(\bar{X}) \centerdot E[n^2] + E^2[\bar{X}] \centerdot Var(n) =  E[n] \centerdot Var(X) + Var(n) \centerdot E^2[X] 
$$

**Next**, because $E[X] = E[\bar{X}]$, I do a simple calculation steps:
$$
Var(\bar{X}) \centerdot E[n^2] + E^2[X] \centerdot Var(n) =  E[n] \centerdot Var(X) + Var(n) \centerdot E^2[X] 
$$

$$
Var(\bar{X}) \centerdot E[n^2] =  E[n] \centerdot Var(X)
$$

And the last equation confused me. In case of constant *n* it gives a result from CLT,  $Var(\bar{X}) \centerdot n = Var(X)$, but why it doesn't contain a correlation part, as in question [Variance of average of  correlated random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391740/variance-of-average-of-n-correlated-random-variables). Am I wrong? Does **formula 2** work in case of correlated variables?

Comment: The variance must clearly increase with increasing correlation so formula #2 can not possibly apply to the case with correlated variables.  Also your use of $\mu$ to represent the sample average (a random variable) is confusing, I would suggest that you use more standard notation such as $\bar X$ instead.

Comment: Thank you @JarleTufto, I replace   by as ¯. As I understand, information from wikipedia about formula #2 is unreliable?

Comment: It was unreliable but not anymore.

Comment: @JarleTufto ahaha. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it looks like we're assuming that $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\mu$, $\mathrm{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$, and $\mathrm{Cov}(X_i, X_j)=\rho \sigma^2$ for all $i,j=1,2,\ldots$, and $i \neq j$.

If we denote by $N$ the number of terms in the sum (which is a random variable), conditioning on $N=n$ gives
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left.\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right|N=n\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)=n\mu
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Var}\left(\left.\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right|N=n\right) = \mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)= n\sigma^2 + n(n-1)\rho \sigma^2.
$$

The law of iterated variances then gives
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right) & = \mathrm{Var}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(\left.\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right|N\right) \right] + \mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm{Var}\left(\left.\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right|N\right) \right]\\
\\
& = \mathrm{Var}(N\mu) + \mathbb{E}(N\sigma^2 + N(N-1)\rho \sigma^2) \\
\\
& = \mu^2 \mathrm{Var}(N)+\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(N) + \rho\sigma^2\left[\mathbb{E}(N^2)-\mathbb{E}(N) \right]
\end{align} 
$$
which is similar to your answer, but you've now got a term that depends on the correlation.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I search for.